# Save change in custom list display using local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I am trying to create a customizable list with links that can be hidden using a class if you click in a button. Also the list have a sortable option that you can move the links on the list, which saves to localstorage.

The problem is that I don't know how to save the class change with the list order in the localstorage if you click the "add/remove" button on each li.

Also, if anyone can help me improve the code I will be grateful, I am a newbie with localstorage and only managed this with a lot of reading in tutorials and documentation.

Here's a working example:

http://codepen.io/RogerHN/pen/EgbOzB

```
var list = document.getElementById('linklist');
var items = list.children;
var itemsArr = [];
for (var i in items) {
    itemsArr.push(items[i]);
}
// localStorage
var ls = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userlist') || '[]');

for (var j = 0; j < ls.length; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < itemsArr.length; ++i) {
        if(itemsArr[i].dataset !== undefined){
            if (ls[j] === itemsArr[i].dataset.id) {
                list.appendChild(itemsArr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

$('.list-block.sortable').on('sort', function () {
    var newIdsOrder = [];
    $(this).find('li').each(function(){
        newIdsOrder.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
    });

    // store in localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('userlist', JSON.stringify(newIdsOrder));
});
```

Comment: What is working and what isn't working? You clearly defined what you want, but you didn't clearly define what isn't currently working.

Comment: Go to the codepen link, click in customize, now if you click remove the list item will be removed from the list when you "click customize again. But that won't be saved like the order of the list (if you click on the right handler you can order the list as you wish, and this order will be saved on local storage, but the removed links don't, and I want to save that information too. I want to save if the li item has the class hidden or not when you close the customize option).

Comment: Forgive me for asking such *an obvious question*, but I can't seem to figure out how to sort the `li`s. What's the trick? (I like your color scheme, by the way. :D)

Comment: What do you mean? Can you be more specific? I like the colors too thanks

Comment: After clicking `customize`, I can't find any option to sort them. Dragging them doesn't do anything, either.

Comment: After clicking customize, click and hold on the hamburger menu icon on the right. If you move it up or down will change the order of the list and save this new order to localstorage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125040/discussion-between-jefre-n-and-rogerhn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
var myApp = new Framework7({
    swipePanel: 'left'
});

// Export selectors engine
var $$ = Dom7;

var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main');

var list = document.getElementById('linklist');
    var items = list.children;
    var itemsArr = [];
    for (var i in items) {
        itemsArr.push(items[i]);
        }

// localStorage
var ls = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userlist') || '[]');
var classes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('classes') || '["","","","","","","","","",""]');

for (var j = 0; j < ls.length; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < itemsArr.length; ++i) {
        if(itemsArr[i].dataset !== undefined){
            if (ls[j] === itemsArr[i].dataset.id) {
                itemsArr[i].className = classes[i];
                list.appendChild(itemsArr[i]);
                // handle [add/remove] thing
                if (classes[i] != "") {
                    $(itemsArr[i]).find(".checky").removeClass("selected");
                    }
                }
            }
        }    
    }

$('.list-block.sortable').on('sort', saveInfo);

$(".restore").click(function(e) {
    $(".confirm").show();
  $(".shadow").show();
});
$(".no,.shadow").click(function(e) {
    $(".confirm").hide();
  $(".shadow").hide();
});
$(".yes").click(function(e) {
    $(".confirm").hide();
});
$(".lbl").click(function(e) {
  $(".toggle-text").toggleClass("blue");
  $(".restore").toggle();
  $(".checky").toggle();
  $("li.hidden").toggleClass("visible");
});
$('.checky').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("selected")) {
        $(this).parent().removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
        }
    else {
        $(this).parent().addClass("hidden visible");
        }
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  saveInfo();
    });

function saveInfo() {
  var newUserList = [];
    var newClassList = [];
    $("#linklist").find('li').each(
        function() {
            newUserList.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
            if ($(this).hasClass("hidden")) {
                newClassList.push("hidden");
                }
            else {
                newClassList.push("");
                }
            });
    // store in localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('userlist', JSON.stringify(newUserList));
    localStorage.setItem('classes', JSON.stringify(newClassList));
    console.log("saved.");
    }

function reset() {
    console.log("Removing data from local storage.");
    localStorage.setItem('userlist', '["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]');
    localStorage.setItem('classes', '["","","","","","","","","",""]');
    window.location.reload(true);
};
```

---

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZpALgj)

<sub>Technically, I should've added explanation...</sub>